# the difference between "here" and "in here"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have this confusion about whether to use "here" or "in here"

For example, if I am in an event and speaking with somebody, and I want to express that someone else is also present in this event. Should I say "xxx(the person's name) is also **in here**" or just  "xxx(the person's name) is also **here**"

Also, when I am travelling in some places and talking with the locals, should I say "I just arrived **here** two days ago" or "I just arrived **in here** two days ago"

Also, do they always have the same meaning?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of "in here" as a more specific version of "here".  In many cases you can substitute "here" for "in here", without really losing any meaning.

> John just texted that he's at the event, so I know he's **in here/ here** somewhere.

However, "in here" is not a substitute for "here", as it means something is *inside*, or at least *within*, some fairly specific location.  While it's possible in your second example, it sounds strange to use "in here" with something like an entire city, because it suggests the person or thing is either visible or can be located with a brief search.

Some examples of using "in here" to emphasis the idea of an *enclosed* area:

> It's too dark **in here**.  Could you turn on another light?
>
> Let me check the pantry.  I know there is sugar **in here** somewhere.
>
> Captain, we have a problem.  I think the alien is **in here** with us.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, if you are in a room or some kind of enclosed space, it would be correct to say, "in here." For example, let's say someone asks you, "Is John Smith here?" You could say, "Yes, he's in here somewhere." Or you could just say, "Yes, he's here." Of course, if the event is outdoors, just say, "He's here." You can't say "in here" if you're outdoors.

Regarding your second question, if you're trying to tell them how long you've been in town, say, "I just arrived here two days ago." "In here" usually refers to being in some kind of enclosed space.